# How large can an charm be?

Tags: juju

I have written a Juju Charm but I need some assets. These assets are 2 to 4 .tar.gz files containing binary data and closed-source library files. Their size is about 10 to 60 MB.

Is it possible to include those .tar.gz files in the Charm in an 'assets' folder? The alternative is to let the Charm download them from a FTP/HTTP site (with a download location Charm configuration option). This however introduces extra dependencies and complexity. As some of the included libraries can only be downloaded when logged in on the vendor's website.

What are approximate size limits for Juju Charms?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! Have you attempted this? It would seem that you have all the pieces in place to test.

Comment: I did not attempted it yet. I was wondering if Juju internally checks for Charm size, if it denies charms larger than 1 GB for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no size limitations for a charm however if you're going to be modifying these assets it's sometimes easier to have them downloaded from an external source than modifying the charm.

Comment: Thank you. I want to scale my charm horizontally by adding more units. So the approach I am going to take is to connect it (with a relation) with a http server that contains my assets. This way I do not multiply assets that are copied to all units. Which is also more efficient.